# Basic java error handling plus variable error

Tags: java, exception

Edit: Solved I had declared the variable out of scope.

So I get an error when trying to compile that says:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable bos
location: class steganography
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

The offending code:

```
//We'll use this to read the file in
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
//We'll use this to push the file out
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
  for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
    bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); 
    //no doubt here is 0
    /*Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this byte array output stream.*/
    System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
  }
} catch (IOException ex) {
 System.out.println(ex);
  //Logger.getLogger(ConvertImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Sorry for not providing more info I am a java n00b.

Comment: The offending code doesn't appear in the routine you cut & pasted, so it's impossible to advise you.  My guess is that it's a scope issue: you think that variable name is visible in that context, but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so sure that is the "offending code" as you put it. Can you show us where this is:

```
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to see the complete problem, as well as the solution to it, if possible! That makes this question and answer more useful for later viewers :)

It looks like you probably declared the variable `bos` out of scope, and therefore the compiler couldn't identify that particular type and its methods. Does this sound like what you did?